# Progress bar causing a ton of browser reflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reflow

I have a progress bar on my website that smoothly updates and it will basically be running the entire time the person is on the site because it's a game element. I noticed if I open the console there is a ton of browser reflow occurring in the browser console log. I basically have no browser reflow being logged without the progress bar and around 100 reflows a second when it is running. So I have four questions:

1) Is this bad? None of the rest of the website seems to be lagging at all but it seems rather disconcerting to have this much stuff constantly being logged in the browser.

2) Is this updating and recomputing the entire page every time a reflow happens or just the area around the progress bar? Anotherwords, is it an efficient operation?

3) Is there any way to turn this off because it's hard to see console errors now because they so quickly get pushed off screen.

4) Is there a way to minimize browser reflow while also have a smoothly updating progress bar? The progress bar is from bootstrap by the way if it matters.

Comment: use <progress>, it's silky-smooth compared to manually hitting style properties over and over...